# What is the best approach to implement background refresh into the app?

Tags: ios, background, refresh, background-foreground, silent-notification

What is the best approach to implement background refresh into the app?
Means which criteria we should take care in approach?
 1. What should be time interval to fetch data in background?
 2. When data will be updated on the screens?
 3. Does it work only in the background?
 4. How much services and data we can fetch in background.
 5. Can we relate (trigger) it with custom events like push/silent notifications.

Please provide possible details, so we can implement it in my app with all possible use-cases.

Thanks in advance.. !!

Comment: you want to refresh data of some screen while in background state ?

Comment: yes, app content should be updated when user come from background to foreground.